# ¿Cómo puedo pasar este codigo Javascript a PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

código que tengo en `javascript` lo uso para generar colores random en formato hexadecimal

```
var randomColor = new Array();
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  randomColor[i] = '#'+Math.random().toString(16).substr(2,6);
}
```

y lo necesito pero en `php`, no conozco de `php` los métodos no se bien como usarlos.

estoy usando laravel como Backend y necesito enviar esto desde el controlador y estoy usando `Str` pero ese no me funciona por el formato.

```
for ($i= 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
   $arrayColores[$i] = '#'. Str::random(6);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @BetaM, gracias, corregí.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes generar un número aleatorio entre 0 y 16777215 ( 16777215  es el equivalente al color blanco o FFFFFF en hex ) con la función `mt_rand` y luego el número obtenido convertirlo a hexadecimal con la función `dechex`.

```
for ($i= 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
   $arrayColores[$i] = '#'.dechex(mt_rand(0, 16777215));
}
```

Más info:

[mt_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mt-rand.php)

[dechex](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.dechex.php)

Comment: muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Esto es lo más simple y sencillo que puedes hacer:

Genera un valor aleatorio RGB y lo convierte a Hexadecimal.
Luego he mostrado codigo y un contenedor, para verificar el color correcto.

```
function rand_color() {
    return '#' . str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF)), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo rand_color();
echo "<div style='background-color: " . rand_color() . "; height:100px; width: 100px;'>";
```

Comment: Tu respuesta se separa demasiado del intento del usuario por resolver el problema, fuera de eso, ni si quiera entiendo qué está pasando en la función `rand_color`, deberías añadir una corta explicación y/o referencia de las funciones que utilizas dentro de `rand_color`

Comment: Se necesita referencia para entender que `mt_rand` es el equivalente a `math.random()` ???